# Moving/Panning an image?

Tags: javascript, html, image, cursor, drag

I'm making a browser game, it's based around a world which you can build on, essentially I have a little user window with a box in, where the world/map is.

Basicly this map is so big so you need to be able to pan it, like click and drag inside the box to move the "map". (The map is essentially a big image)

Now there's a problem with images and dragging. When I click and drag on an image it assumes I want to "copy" it or drag it somewhere.

I tried to replace it with a normal div and it works so the code is fine. And I don't want to place the image as a background image either.

So my question is, how do I "disable" the "drag picture somewhere" feature? Whenever I try to click and drag on a picture, on any website, my cursor changes to a "no" sign, it means that I can't drop it there and if I'd move it into lets say photoshop, it'll change to this "drop pic here" cursor.

EDIT

Sorry for me not researching, I found out that you can do;

[element].ondragstart = function() { return false; };

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
[element].ondragstart = function() { return false; };
```

as you suggested, or I also think you could solve this by absolutely positioning another div on top of the image, just as a "control layer". That way you could write js that responds to mouse interactions in that div without worrying about the image at all.